# Show database records with json

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, json

I am building a simple app with Intel XDK and I need to connect my app to a mysql database. Because the Intel XDK does not allow PHP files I needed to connect my html to php via javascrapt and json.

Here is the PHP code I found and edited which sends an PHP array as JSON object to the Intel XDK app:

```
    <?php

if(isset($_GET["get_rows"]))
{
    //checks the format client wants
    if($_GET["get_rows"] == "json")
    {
        $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "xxxx", "xxxx", "xxxx");

        /* check connection */
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo mysqli_connect_error();
            header("HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error");
            exit();
        }

        $query = "SELECT * FROM quotes LIMIT 1";

        $jsonData = array();

        if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

            /* fetch associative array */
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
                $jsonData = $row;
            }

            /* free result set */
            mysqli_free_result($result);

            //encode to JSON format

            echo  "<h1>" . json_encode($jsonData) . "</h1>";

        }
        else {

           echo  "<h1>" . json_encode($jsonData) . "</h1>";
        }

        /* close connection */
        mysqli_close($link);
    }
    else
    {
        header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    }
}
else
{
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
}

?>
```

My index.html has the following code:

```
<head>
    <script>
                function GetQuote() {
                var xmlhttp;
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                  }
                else
                  {// code for IE6, IE5
                  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                  }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                  {
                  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                    {
                    document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                  }
                xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://domain/db.php?get_rows=json", false);
                xmlhttp.send();
                }
    </script>    
    </head>

    <body onload="GetQuote()">

        <div id="quote">     </div>

    </body>
```

My code is working and my app shows the latest row in my table. The problem is that this code returns the entire row so I get someting like this on my screen:
["column1","column2"]. What I need is "Column1" as a record and "column2" as a record.

Anyone who can help me? I've been working on this problem the entire day and can't find a solution.. Thanks!

---

This is the code I have now:

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET["get_rows"]))
{
    //checks the format client wants
    if($_GET["get_rows"] == "json")
    {
        $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "xxx", "xxxx", "xxxx");

        /* check connection */
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo mysqli_connect_error();
            header("HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error");
            exit();
        }

        $query = "SELECT quote, author FROM quotes WHERE id = " . date('d');

        $jsonData = array();

        if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

            /* fetch associative array */
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc($result);

        // Create a new array and assign the column values to it
         // You can either turn an associative array or basic array
        $ret= array();

        $ret[] = $row['quote']; 
        $ret[] = $row['author']; 

            //encode to JSON format

            echo  json_encode($ret);

        }

        else {

            echo  json_encode($ret);
        }

        /* close connection */
        mysqli_close($link);
    }
    else
    {
        header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    }
}
else
{
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
}


?>
```

I now just get an empty screen with [null,null].. Anyone knows what's wrong with this code? I tried debugging, but I am new to PHP and I can't manage to make it work.. Thanks!

Comment: You are invalidating your own json by putting html tags around it. You should only output json and nothing else.

Comment: Use column1 and column2 names to get the results in your query, instead of using asterisk (*), save each column value in an array and convert that array to json and return :)

Comment: @MTahir how would I need to do that? Sorry but it has been a long day and I really want it to work.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
    $query = "SELECT column1,column2 FROM quotes LIMIT 1";

    $jsonData = array();

    if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

        /* fetch associative array */
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc($result);

         // Create a new array and assign the column values to it
         // You can either turn an associative array or basic array
        $ret= array();
        $ret['name1'] = $row['column1']; 
        $ret['name2'] = $row['column2']; 
        // Or you can simply use, comment the above two lines and uncomment the following two lines.
        //$ret[] = $row['column1']; 
        //$ret[] = $row['column2']; 


        //encode to JSON format

        echo  json_encode($ret);
```

If you find any type error here, kindly share

Comment: Thanks, that's very kind of you. But it doesn't work.. I now get: [null,null] as result on my screen..

Comment: I am new to PHP so I'm not yet familiar with debugging.. I can't copy the code I have now in this comment so I will just post it as an 'answer' (I know that's actuelly not allowed, sorry..)